# Why I get error Polymer::Attributes: couldn`t decode Array as JSON?

Tags: json, ajax, polymer

I have an API (http://localhost:8080/testapi) with this JSON :

```
{"cars":[{"color":"Blue","miles":100,"vin":"1234"},{"color":"Red","miles":200,"vin":"1235"}]}
```

And I would like to display the result :

```
    <iron-ajax url="http://localhost:8080/testapi" handle-as="json" on-response="handleResponse" last-response="{{cars}}" auto></iron-ajax>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[cars]]">
    <div>[[item.color]]</div>
</template>
```

But I get an error with this above code. Do you know where is my mistake ?

Many thanks.

Comment: shouldn't you use `items=[[cars.cars]]` ? because you are settings response to property car, but inside this property you have `car` key

Comment: It doesn't work. I have the same error. I think the problem comes from the <iron-ajax> because if I comment the template, I can see the same error :
case Array:
try {
value = JSON.parse(value);
} catch (x) {
value = null;
console.warn('Polymer::Attributes: couldn`t decode Array as JSON');
}